# How to create a multiple-column table of contents?

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

Given some latex code like

```
    \section{the first section}
    some text

    \section{the second section}
    some text

    \section{the third section}
    some text

    \section{the fourth section}
    some text
```

I want to create a TOC as a three-column table, like so:

```
    -------------------------------------------------
    | 1. the first  | 2. the second | 3. the third  |
    |    section    |    section    |    section    |
    -------------------------------------------------
    | 4. the fourth |               |               |
    |    section    |               |               |
    -------------------------------------------------
```

It is okay if I use a completely custom command instead  of `section`, as long as the numbering in the document body matches the numbering in the table.

How can I approach this problem?

Comment: Perhaps the `etoc` package provides some means for this

Comment: @SoundsOfSilence yes it does, as described in an "advanced section for advanced users" `:-)`. But anyhow the accepted answer isn't a `table`...

Comment: @jfbu: And my answer is neither using your package nor is it accepted ... that's life ;-) I think, you should add an answer as well!

Comment: @SoundsOfSilence I did, but after all maybe it's not that different from your own which uses as well `longtable`.

Comment: @jfbu: But it does look better than mine;-)

Comment: @SoundsOfSilence it's all due to the nice vertical rules we are supposed not to use in tables `:-)`

Comment: @jfbu: I won't tell egreg about your vertical lines :-P

Comment: @SoundsOfSilence impossible. He knows everything happening here !

Comment: The `tables` tag is correct in this case as the OP wants a ToC in tabular form

Comment: L.S., Can someone give me any clue on how to implement the solution provided by user4686 but make the cells adjust to the content that is displayed in it? I'm currently having issues that the contents fall outside of the cell borders and was wondering if there was any solution to this? (I'm pretty new to Latex and am struggling to implement this) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\l@section#1#2{%
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr(.333\linewidth)-2em\relax}%
\def\numberline##1{##1: }\parfillskip0pt\relax
#1 \mbox{}\dotfill #2\end{minipage}\linebreak[0]\hspace{2em plus 2em}}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

    \section{the first section}
    some text

    \section{the second section}
    some text

    \section{the third section}
    some text

    \section{the fourth section}
    some text

\end{document}
```

Comment: I wrapped the minipage in an `\fbox{...}` and removed the hspace and it works great!

Answer (score 7):

Here is (another way) to do it in a longtable, here using package `etoc`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[hscale=0.8]{geometry}

\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}

% It is not at all obvious to display a TOC in a (long)-table,
% using etoc, but it is possible. See in its doc
% "Typesetting the TOC as a table".

% Let's illustrate here in a case which has only sections.
% We will use the *standard* way of displaying the sections in the TOC, except
% it will all take places in p cells of a longtable.


\usepackage[linktoc=all]{hyperref}% let's increase the challenge !

\newcounter{column}
\newtoks\toctabletok

\newcommand*\appendtotok[2]
{% #1=toks variable, #2=macro, 
 % #2 will be expanded once.
   #1\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\the\expandafter #1#2}%
}

\makeatletter % for \l@section

\newcommand*{\PrepareSectionCell}{%
  \toks0 \expandafter{\etocthelinkednumber}% don't worry, etoc always in a group
  \toks2 \expandafter{\etocthelinkedname}%
  \toks4 \expandafter{\etocthelinkedpage}%
% or we could use \unexpanded  from e-TeX, rather than the \toks registers
  \edef\toctablecell {\relax % mandatory to stop TeX's future too 
                             % early expansion of cell
    \noexpand\par % \l@section MUST start in vertical mode
    \noexpand\vspace*{-\baselineskip}% compensate for the \par (I think)
    \noexpand\l@section % call the hotline if you have unnumbered sections
          {\noexpand\numberline{\the\toks0 }\noexpand\strut\the\toks2 }{\the\toks4 }%
    }%
}

%
\newcommand*{\TableTableOfContents}{\begingroup
%
  \etocsetstyle{section}{}{}
  {\PrepareSectionCell
   \appendtotok\toctabletok\toctablecell
   \stepcounter{column}%
   \ifnum\value{column}=3
    \toctabletok \expandafter{\the\toctabletok \\\hline}%
    \setcounter{column}{0}%
   \else
    \toctabletok \expandafter{\the\toctabletok &}%
   \fi}
  {}
%
  \etocsettocstyle
  {\toctabletok{%\hypersetup{hidelinks}%
                \begin{longtable}{*{3}{|p{.3\linewidth}}|}
                \hline
                \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\Large\bfseries\strut TABLE OF CONTENTS}%
                \\
                \hline\hline}}
  {\ifcase\value{column}%
          \or\toctabletok\expandafter{\the\toctabletok &\\\hline}%
          \or\toctabletok\expandafter{\the\toctabletok  \\\hline}%
   \fi 
   \global\toctabletok\expandafter{\the\toctabletok \end{longtable}}%
   }
%
  \etocsetnexttocdepth {section}%
  \tableofcontents
  \endgroup
  \the\toctabletok % the only thing which survived the closing of the group
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\TableTableOfContents

    \section{the first section}
    some text

    \section{the second section}
    some text

    \section{the third section}
    some text

    \section{the fourth section}
    some text


\newcount\loopcount
\loopcount 50

\loop
  \section {and another section}
  hello
\clearpage
\advance\loopcount-1
\ifnum\loopcount>0
\repeat 

  \section {and the final section which happens to have quite a long name. By
    the way you can click on it, its number or the page number}

\end{document}
```

[image: etoc table top of first page]

and then continued on page 2:

[image: etoc table continued on page 2]

I add some extra info: there is a difference between a `p` column in a `longtable` and a `p` column in a standard tabular. The latter starts in vertical mode. But the former's `p` cell contents typesetting does not start in vertical mode. As a result, the `\l@section` which could have been used directly in a `tabular` at the start of a cell (after `\relax`) needed here in the `longtable` an extra `\par`. I then needed to compensate the resulting `\baselineskip`. There is a remnant vertical space which is due to the `\addvspace{1em plus 1pt}` done by `\l@section`.

As for the vertical space below the section names it is due to the fact that when a `p` column finishes, an (invisible) `\vrule` is added by macro `\@finalstrut`. Here this is the same in a `tabular` as in a `longtable`.  In both cases this provokes a switch to horizontal mode hence again some vertical space.

In brief, using `\l@section` inside `longtable` was fun, but I should presumably rather have used the `\etocthename` etc... things directly and not wrap them up in `\l@section` (see the documentation of [etoc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc) for an example in section "Typesetting the TOC as a table").

Comment: I opened the `pdf` in  Adobe Reader, to get the red rectangles to explicitely illustrate the presence of the links; as is known, these rectangles don't show in some other viewers nor in print.

Comment: I don't know why I absolutely wanted to use `\l@section`... after all it was not designed to be used in such a context! but well, it does work.

Comment: `Most impressive` my favourite character from Star Wars would say (+1)

Comment: @SoundsOfSilence the Epsiode III is of Shakespearean stature! not like my table where I am not so sure I understand the vertical spacings...

Answer (score 4):

Another approach with the current disadvantage (amongst others) that it's necessary to delete the `.tabtoc` file later by hand.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{longtable}%
\usepackage{hyperref}


\NewDocumentCommand{\TableOfContents}{}{%
\section*{\contentsname}%
\begin{longtable}{*{3}{p{4cm}}}
& & \tabularnewline[1ex]
\InputIfFileExists{\jobname.tabtoc}{\typeout{File exists}}{\typeout{File does not exist}} \tabularnewline[2ex]
\end{longtable}%
}%


\newwrite\tabtoc%


\makeatletter



\newcounter{@@columncounter}
\setcounter{@@columncounter}{0}

\xapptocmd{\@sect}{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}. }
  \protect\addtocounter{@@columncounter}{1}%
  \immediate\write\tabtoc{%
    \thesection #7 % \tabularnewline
  }%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{@@columncounter}}{2}{%
    \immediate\write\tabtoc{%
      \string\tabularnewline[1ex]^^J
    }%
    \setcounter{@@columncounter}{0}
  }{%
    \immediate\write\tabtoc{&}
  }%
  \endgroup
}{%
\typeout{success}}{\typeout{fail}}

\makeatother
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \IfFileExists{\jobname.tabtoc}{%
    % Do nothing
  }{%
    % Open it for writing 
    \immediate\openout\tabtoc=\jobname.tabtoc%
  }%
}%

\AtEndDocument{%
\immediate\closeout\tabtoc
}


\begin{document}

\TableOfContents

\section{First}

\section{Second}
\section{Third}

\section{Fourth}

\section{Fifth}
\section{Sixth}
\section{Seventh with a very long wrapping title}
\section{Eight}


\end{document}
```

[image]