# Sub-Toc with Multiple Colums

Tags: table-of-contents, longtable, etoc

---

> Using `etoc`, I would like to display a multi-column `\localtableofcontents` on the cover page of a part, with a column for each chapter.
>
> One way to go might be the use of `longtable`.

---

Using the `etoc`, `titlesec` and `titletoc` packages, the local tocs can be produced by the MWE below

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{report}

\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc} % to take control of part-page

% take control of the part-page
\titleformat{\part}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\filcenter\bfseries}
  {\partname\ \thepart}{0pt}{}
\titleclass{\part}{top}

\begin{document}

\part{A Part}
\etocsettocstyle{}{}
\etocsetnexttocdepth{section}
\localtableofcontents

\chapter{A Chapter}
\section{A Section}
\section{B Section}

\chapter{B Chapter}
\section{A Section}
\section{B Section}
\section{C Section}

\end{document}
```

rendering a subtoc on the part's cover page, as desired:

[image]

By combining the `etoc` package with `longtable` - as @user4686 did to [solve a related problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227924/how-to-create-a-multiple-column-table-of-contents) - it should be possible to obtain the same in multiple columns:

[image]

However, as I don't fully understand @user4648's snippet, I don't know which lines to change and how.

Answer (score 1):

Using longtable or similar seems a strange and impractical choice. It should be as simple as this

```
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength\columnsep{33pt} % Adjust to taste
\raggedcolumns
```

...

```
\part{A Part}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\etocsettocstyle{}{}
\etocsetnexttocdepth{section}
\localtableofcontents
\end{multicols}
```

Comment: This is elegant and works indeed nicely for the MWE. But I would like to ensure that every chapter starts a new column. Changing the last section name to `\section{C Section with a much longer name}` demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Btw, is there a way to enable hyphenation on the toc?

Comment: Is it practical to have each chapter in a separate column? How many chapters are there?  You could insert `\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{\textheight}}` before each `\chapter` command, except the first.

Comment: Also, "C Section with a much longer name" demonstrated the trouble with 3 or 4 columns. I really think two columns are the most you can use decently. The word "Section" should be hyphenated for 3 columns.

Comment: Just two columns/chapters. `\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{\textheight}}` unfortunately also affects the main toc. Is it possible to have the additional rows of a multi-row section title to be `\raggedright`

Comment: This etoc you are using seems incredibly configurable. Surely it can do ragged-right, so check the documentation. If not, search stackexchange, and then maybe ask a separate question.  Also, my comment for separating columns will, unfortunately, also apply to the main TOC, if there is one.